# User input causes frame.getContentPane.removeAll() to stop working

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jpanel

Within a JFrame , i am replacing a Jpanel with another JPanel .

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Testing extends JPanel {

    JLabel jl;
    ImageIcon icon;
    Point pointer;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       JFrame jf = new JFrame();

       JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
       JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();

       JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Hey1");
       JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Hey2");

       jp1.add(jl1);
       jp2.add(jl2);

       jf.add(jp1);

       jf.setVisible(true);
       jf.pack();

       Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(System.in);

       int x = myScanner.nextInt(); // the line causes the code to not work , 

                                    //    what is happening

       jf.getContentPane().removeAll();

       jf.add(jp2);


    }
}
```

The weird part is that the code stops working the moment i try to read user input

> int x = myScanner.nextInt();

The code :  `jf.getContentPane().removeAll();` stops working and i cant remove the current JPanel and add in the new JPanel

i need to read in the user input before the JPanel is replaced , how do i resolve this issue??

**note : Even after i type in something , the jf.getContentPane().removeAll() still doesnt work**

Comment: `Scanner#nextInt` waits for user input. It will hang until user enters something in the console. Anyway, why are you use `removeAll/add` to switch `JPanel`s? You can use `CardLayout` for that purpose.

Comment: @BackSlash even after i type in something , the jf.getContentPane().removeAll() still doesnt work

Comment: Try adding a `repaint()` or a `revalidate()` **after** the `removeAll` call. But again, that's not the right way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `validate()` to  layout the container's subcomponents. Also `pack()` the `Window` *before* 
`setVisible()`.

Alternatively, use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to change the view and [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to collect user input.

As tested:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Testing extends JPanel {

    JLabel jl;
    ImageIcon icon;
    Point pointer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Hey1");
        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Hey2");
        jp1.add(jl1);
        jp2.add(jl2);
        jf.add(jp1);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = myScanner.nextInt(); // the line causes the code to not work , 
        jf.getContentPane().removeAll();
        jf.add(jp2);
        jf.validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @Computernerd: `validate()` causes the frame's container to layout its subcomponents again; note that `pack()` invokes `validate()`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that is not that the program is "stop working" at this line:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Of course this line needs that you insert some integer value in the console, but this works perfectly.

Actually your program does NOT stop to work: it simply executes all the expressions and then wait for ever, it does not end because there is the GUI thread that loops for ever.

The point is that that the methods that you call are not correct in order to obtain the desired result, please check my code (modified in the last lines) if this can suite your requirments:

```
public class Testing extends JPanel {

    JLabel jl;
    ImageIcon icon;
    Point pointer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();

        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("Hey1");
        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("Hey2");

        jp1.add(jl1);
        jp2.add(jl2);

        jf.add(jp1);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = myScanner.nextInt(); // the line causes the code to not work , 

                                    //    what is happening
        jf.setContentPane(jp2);
        jf.pack();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: 1. Don't post "just code". If you do that, the OP will learn nothing from your answer, explain what you did and why. 2. How is this going to help the OP?

Comment: I'm sorry I've copy-paste the code that I tried and posted the comment involuntarily, but I quickly added some comments and explanations.

Comment: Your "comments" are wrong. Declaring a `Scanner` will not make the program hang.

Comment: In fact I wrote: "The problem that is NOT that the program is "stop working" at this line": I explained that the problem is somewhere else... I've also illustrated why the programs seems to hang, but in fact is does not, due to the GUI thread