# Does using GUI's JFrame cancels the Scanner class?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner

I created a JFrame window with some buttons and I want to make it when a user click a specific button a method will be launched and the method will use a scanner object to pick up information from the user.

For some reason after I click that button from the frame, the method launches but I am not able to type any info.

Is there a way to use JFrame and Scanner class at the same application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [User input causes frame.getContentPane.removeAll() to stop working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150971/user-input-causes-frame-getcontentpane-removeall-to-stop-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is definitely a way to use both of them at the same time. You just cannot use the `Scanner` to take input from the command line.

A program in Java should either be a GUI application or a Console application, but not both. Once you bring up a `JFrame`, your code should not be reading from console. What you should do is adding input fields to your GUI (e.g. a `JTextField`) and read a `String` from it. You can pass the `String` that you read to a `Scanner` to subdivide it into tokens. Alternatively, you could make multiple text input fields, and take your input that way.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work... my `JFrame` is up but I can still call `scanner.nextLine()` [after `scanner = new Scanner(system.in)`] and it gets the data.  (This is on Windows.)  Definitely agree that this is a poor interface, although maybe OK as a temporary debugging measure during development if it works.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the comment! I remember trying this very long time ago, and it did not work for me. This was back when Java 1.2 came out, though, so it's definitely not a current knowledge. I edited the question to make it sound more like a recommendation.

Comment: @ajb: It may require some effort to synchronize a `Scanner` running on the initial thread with the GUI running on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod Could be right.  My test was a very simple one just to see if input could be entered from Command Prompt while the JFrame was up, but I didn't do anything fancy.